# Preloading Data in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have some data with me which I want to upload to Cognito before starting using it. Is there any way of pre-loading the data before using Cognito?

Thanks
Puneet

Comment: Not sure what data you would need to pre-load, since "Amazon Cognito is a web service that delivers scoped temporary credentials to mobile devices and other untrusted environments." Can you explain further?

Comment: Hi David, I am migrating data from parse to cognito. I need to transfer all the data which is there in parse to Cognito before start using it so that I can stop using parse and start using Cognito. I am not sure how can I go for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cognito Sync Service doesn't have an automated import tool for data, unfortunately.

It could be possible, but it would require you to write your own tool to do it. Cognito does allow developer write access to the sync store, so if you don't have a large number of users, it could be done manually through the identity browser. With several, you would need a tool to link Cognito users to your Parse users.